# How to reuse common codes for structs?

Tags: rust

I want to reuse codes for structs. For example:

```rust
use std::fmt::Display;

struct CommonStruct<T: Display> {
    // could have more fields
    data: T
}

struct A<T: Display> {
    com: CommonStruct<T>,
    age: i32
}

struct B<T: Display> {
    com: CommonStruct<T>,
    name: String
}

impl<T: Display> A<T> {
    // could be more common functions
    fn print_data(&self) {
        // could be more complicated
        println!("data: {}", self.com.data);
    }
}

impl<T: Display> B<T> {
    // could be more common functions
    fn print_data(&self) {
        // could be more complicated
        println!("data: {}", self.com.data);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A{ com: CommonStruct{data: 10}, age: 0 };
    a.print_data();
    let b = B{ com: CommonStruct{data: 12}, name: "123".to_string() };
    b.print_data();
}
```

where `A` and `B` have some common fields packed by `CommonStruct` and some common functions (e.g., `print_data`).

I tried to use `trait` but cannot figure out a solution:

```rust
use std::fmt::Display;

struct CommonStruct<T: Display> {
    // could have more fields
    data: T
}

struct A<T: Display> {
    com: CommonStruct<T>,
    age: i32
}

struct B<T: Display> {
    com: CommonStruct<T>,
    name: String
}

trait Common {
    // could be more common functions
    fn print_data(&self) {
        print_data(&self)
    }
}

impl<T: Display> Common for A<T> {
}

impl<T: Display> Common for B<T> {
}

fn print_data(t: &Common) {
    // could be more complicated
    println!("data: {}", t.com.data);
}

fn main() {
    let a = A{ com: CommonStruct{data: 10}, age: 0 };
    a.print_data();
    let b = B{ com: CommonStruct{data: 12}, name: "123".to_string() };
    b.print_data();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `print_data` only uses the CommonStruct, and A and B share no other fields, make it an implementation of CommonStruct and call it directly.

```
impl <T: Display> CommonStruct<T> {
    fn print_data(&self) {
        println!("data: {}", self.data);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A{ com: CommonStruct{data: 10}, age: 0 };
    a.com.print_data();
    let b = B{ com: CommonStruct{data: 12}, name: "123".to_string() };
    b.com.print_data();
}
```

---

Alternatively, make a trait which has a concrete implementation of `print_data` which relies on a method to get the data.

```
trait HasData<T: Display> {
    fn get_data(&self) -> &T;
    fn print_data(&self) {
        // could be more complicated
        println!("data: {}", self.get_data());
    }
}
```

Then each only has to implement how to get the data.

```
impl<T: Display> HasData<T> for CommonStruct<T> {
    fn get_data(&self) -> &T {
        return &self.data;
    }
}

impl<T: Display> HasData<T> for A<T> {
    fn get_data(&self) -> &T {
        return &self.com.data;
    }
}

impl<T: Display> HasData<T> for B<T> {
    fn get_data(&self) -> &T {
        return &self.com.data;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A{ com: CommonStruct{data: 1}, age: 0 };
    a.print_data();
    let b = B{ com: CommonStruct{data: 2}, name: "123".to_string() };
    b.print_data();
    let c = CommonStruct{data: 3};
    c.print_data();
}
```

Comment: struct `A` and `B` have different fields (e.g., in this case, I simplified to `a` and `b` which have different types). The solution you gave is not equivalent to the original code because `a` and `b` become generic types.

Comment: For example, I gave `a` a meaningful name `age`, and give `b` a meaningful name `user_name`. I cannot combine these two structs.

Comment: It worked. But is there any way to call `a.print_data()` directly? Because I don't want to expose details, which means users might not be able to access `com`.

Comment: @HaoLi See edits. There's probably also a way to eliminate the `get_data` duplication, I'm not a Rust expert.

Comment: Thank you! Based on this approach, I have to write all `get` methods for all fields I need in the `Common` struct. It is complicated but worked. I still hope there have some elegant methods.

Comment: @HaoLi Your data structures are very abstract, which makes it hard to make good suggestions. It's very likely that there is a better solution for whatever problem you are actually facing.

Comment: @trentcl Yes, I understand. I will try to build a prototype first. This answer could be a good starting point for me. I will post new questions when I encountered problems.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you wanted to use [traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html). I've included a working example below.

However, traits are used to implement *shared behavior*. A trait must be implemented on each type you wish to have the *shared behavior*. So, you do have to `impl` a separate `print_data` function for a given type.

```
use std::fmt::Display;

// `Common` structure of some type `T`.
struct Common<T: Display> {
    data: T,
}

// `Printable` trait used to print `data`.
trait Printable {
    fn print_data(&self);
}

struct A {
    common: Common<String>,
}

impl A {
    fn new(s: &str) -> A {
        A {
            common: Common { data: s.to_owned() },
        }
    }
}

// Implement `Printable the trait for A`.
impl Printable for A {
    fn print_data(&self) {
        println!("A.common.data: {}", self.common.data)
    }
}

struct B {
    common: Common<i32>,
}

// Implement the `Printable` trait for `B`.
impl Printable for B {
    fn print_data(&self) {
        println!("B.common.data: {}", self.common.data)
    }
}
```

So that's traits, but if you must call the same function to print the data, then maybe something like the following can work for you. It defines an `enum` with three variants. You can then `match` on a particular variant as demonstrated by `print_all_data`.

```
use std::path::PathBuf;
struct G {
    path: PathBuf,
    common: Common<String>,
}

enum C {
    D(A),
    E(B),
    F(G),
}

fn print_all_data(c: C) {
    match c {
        C::D(a) => println!("{}", a.common.data),
        C::E(b) => println!("{}", b.common.data),
        C::F(g) => println!("{} {:?}", g.common.data, g.path)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A::new("hello");
    a.print_data();

    let b = B {
        common: Common { data: 42 },
    };
    b.print_data();

    let g = G {
        path: PathBuf::from("some/path/file.txt"),
        common: Common {data: "some_data".to_owned()}
    };

    let cfg = C::F(g);
    print_all_data(cfg);
    print_all_data(C::D(a));
    print_all_data(C::E(b));
}
```

Comment: I want to reuse code, they could have more functions and the functions could be more complicated. In this answer, you repeat the `print_data` for `A` and `B`.

Comment: Of course. When you use traits you're implementing _shared behavior_. You have to implement the different behavior for each concrete type. I updated my answer to show how you could use the same function to operate on a given enum (each of which can "wrap" some other, arbitrarily complex, type).